# QField Cloud - some layers remain read-only despite different configuration in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield, cloud-gis, qgis-cloud

I am working with QGIS and QField Cloud for a while now and despite having to regularly solve sync issues, I'm quite happy with QFieldCloud for my purposes (collecting data in the field).

But now I encountered a sync problem for which I can't find any solution despite having tried every possible sync setting in QGIS and QField and searched the entire internet:

Every time I create a new layer (e.g. a vector layer) and sync it to QFieldCloud, the layer is marked as "read-only" after updating the app.
The layer is stored in the usual QField Cloud folder on my desktop computer where all other editable layers are stored, too. In Project Properties - Data Sources, all layers are set as "Identifiable" and "Searchable", no layer is set as "Read-only". The layers I want to edit while in the field are set to "Offline Editing" in the QField Properties - Action tab.

In order to identify the error, I configured older layers as "Read-only" - after syncing, they were correctly marked as "Read-only" in the app. Switching this setting back also worked. I also recreated several new layers, reinstalled the QField app and synced the entire project again, but the problem keeps persisting: Newly added layers remain read-only despite configured differently.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

I am using QGIS LTR version 3.28.9 and QField 2.8.3

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same thing and discovered that the problem was the file type : new shapefile layers showed as "read only" when uploaded in to QField. Solved the problem by adding new Geopackage layers instead of shapefiles.